# jaxb unmarshalling with other class as property

Tags: java, jaxb

I have this two model.
AssetMetadata:

```
        @XmlRootElement(name="AssetMetadata")
        public class AssetMetadata {

        private AssetMetadataType assetMetadataType;
        private String id;
        private String assetId; 
        ....
```

AssetMetadataType:

```
        @XmlRootElement(name = "AssetMetadataType")
        public class AssetMetadataType {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        ....
```

I use the JaxB unmarshaller like this.
spring config:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="ch.srf.esb.radioimporter.domain.AssetMetadata"/>
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="ch.srf.esb.radioimporter.domain.AssetMetadataType"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

Java code:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("marshaller") private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
...
final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
this.unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
```

Now when I send the following XML, the AssetMetadataType is not set:

```
<AssetMetadata>
  <AssetMetadataType>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>EPG</name>
  </AssetMetadataType>
  <assetId>39b4864d-931b-40c6-85ad-c45251b97952</assetId>
  <title>title</title>
  <description>description</description>
</AssetMetadata>
```

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@XmlRootElement` should only be set on the root element. That's why it's called `@XmlRootElement`. It'll be ignored anywhere else.

Try removing `@XmlRootElement` from the `AssetMetadataType` class, and change the property in `AssetMetadata` to be:

```
@XmlElement(name="AssetMetadataType")
private AssetMetadataType assetMetadataType;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get this exception then:    Class has two properties of the same name "assetMetadataType"

Comment: OK you were right: I had to remove the getAssetMetadataType() and setAssetMetadataType() methods in the AssetMetadata model. Now It works. Thank You.

Comment: +1 - @shifty, you don't need to remove any methods.  Just be sure you either annotate the get methods, or if you want to annotate the field (instance variable) then set @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: Thanks again. Works like a charms now with the annotated Getter method